# Check file sizes of content inside ZIP archive

Tags: php, zip, filesize

I need to open a ZIP archive, check the file size of each file inside the archive and return an array with the numeric values (sizes). I don't want the archive to be extracted to check the file sizes, possibly.

I tried a lot myself, but no ZIP function seems to have a feature like that and I couldn't think of any combination to write the function myself.

Comment: ZipArchive::statIndex does not work for you?

Comment: [`ZipArchive::statIndex()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.statindex.php) is what you're looking for, if you just need to collect information about the archived files.

Comment: Well, this must have slipped away somehow, but thanks, will try to get a function out of it.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is pretty old. I hope this answer could help someone.
The following code cycles up all the files inside the **`test2.zip`** file and prints its name and the sizes in bytes.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test2.zip');
if ($res) {
    $i=0;
    while(!empty($zip->statIndex($i)['name']))
    {
       echo "Filename: ".$zip->statIndex($i)['name']." | Size: ".$zip->statIndex($i)['size']." bytes<br>";
       $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Filename: main.php | Size: 44 bytes
Filename: test.php | Size: 385 bytes
Filename: test2.json | Size: 35 bytes
Filename: Token.txt | Size: 5 bytes
Filename: trans.png | Size: 95442 bytes
Filename: url_xml.xml | Size: 399 bytes
```

Comment: You can also use [`ZipArchive::statName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.statname.php) if you know the exact path inside the ZIP archive.